# Add new model or extend existing one?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Hi I have a model Workout and model Set.

Workout `has_many` sets, set `belongs_to` workout.

Set has certain properties, like number of repetitions for left hand, for right hand, total repetitions etc.

Now I'm in front of a dilemma how to create additional/different kind of sets with different properties (say set for time, set that goal is to reach certain number of repetitions etc.)

Should I extend set model and change form via javascript based on some choice (it would be easier with counting statistics out of sets but IMHO it would make validation more complicated) or shall I create new kind of sets?

Ideas/tips ?

Thank you

Petr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd create a new model but If they're similar enough I'd use Single Table Inheritance and simply inherit say the statistics methods from Set.

Comment: Thanks Jakub, that would do the trick. I learn something new every day ;)